# Why doesn't my AJAX script work?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to get the below code to call to a PHP file, and show the returned data. In Firefox, the alert shows blank, and in IE it shows sometimes but mostly nothing. The PHP script is a simple `echo "hello";`.

#### The script

```
function make_request()
{
  try
  {
    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    // Internet Explorer
    try
    {
      httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      try
      {
        httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}


function check_login(username, password)
{
  var httpRequest;
  make_request()

  var parameters = 'username=' + username.value + '&password=' + password.value;
  httpxml.onreadystatechange = stateck;
  httpxml.open('POST', 'login.php', true);
  httpxml.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  httpxml.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', parameters.length);
  httpxml.send(parameters);

  function stateck() 
  {
    if(httpxml.readyState==4)
    {
      alert(httpxml.responseText);  
    }
  }
}
```

#### The markup

```
<table class="form" id="form" cellpadding="10" >
  <form id="signup_form" name="form" method="post" />
  <tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="26" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="26"/></td>
  </tr>

    <td>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" onClick="check_login(username, password);"/>
    </td>
  </form>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you leverage an existing framework for this??

Comment: Am working on learning jquery..

Comment: Your code is incomplete so not really helpful for us... among other things check_login function is not closed.... could you update?

Comment: Only thing missing is the html input boxes....check_login function is closed?

Comment: you're right - my bad. don't have glasses on so missed the obvious scrollbars :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes that I couldn't fit into a comment (some of these should have no effect on the success of your XMLHttpRequest call; others *might* - so fix *all* of them):

#### The script

Nothing checks the return value of *make_request()*, so `return false;` is sorta pointless (just... return). Why not make *httpxml* a local variable instead of an implicit global, and return that? Then use the return value to indicate to the caller whether or not the function succeeded...

The local variable *httpRequest* in *check_login()* is never used. Perhaps you intended to assign it the return value of *make_request()* (and... have *make_request()* actually return something useful?)

You're not actually URL-encoding the values of *username* or *password*. (Pass them through [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) to accomplish this easily)

You should not need to set the `Content-Length` header explicitly. (And if you get it wrong, this could easily cause the request to fail)

**And the worst script error:** you're not canceling the default behavior for the submit button. Return false from *check_login()*, and change your event handler to `onclick="return check_login(username, password);`

#### The markup

You've made your `<form>` tag self-closing (`<form ... />`). And included a closing `</form>` tag. It's unlikely that's what you want (and even less likely that'll behave reliably cross-browser)

Your last cell (`<td>`) is defined outside of any row (`<tr>`).

You close a `<div>` that was never opened.

Comment: Thanks for that...I forgot to edit out the last div when I copied it.

Comment: And another tiny thing: As you're using XHTML, all HTML attributes should be defined lowercase, so onClick should be onclick.
Also, you could better use the onsubmit-attribute on the <form> instead.

Comment: It works once in IE about every 5mins I try...for a strange reason, in firefox it doesnt work at all.

Comment: Firebug doesnt really show much...shows the post data is sent, but I carnt view much more as it re-loads and the console is cleared.

Comment: @Elliott: HA! Add `return false;` to the end of `check_login()` to prevent the form from being submitted... This *should* fall apart in IE as well, but perhaps FF is just a bit quicker at reloading the page...

Comment: firebug now shows the response " hello "...thanks @ shog9, I forgot that :p

Comment: username [object HTMLInputElement] - This is shown for the post data?

Comment: Updated answer. I'd missed that you were passing in the form fields as parameters somehow, as well as the missing return. Don't forget to extract the *value* of the form fields (as you were doing originally) and pass them through encodeURIComponent() before submission...

Comment: Some how got it working by changing the "onClick" to "onclick"

Thanks alot guys =D